# Changing an object which is used as a Map key

Tags: java, dictionary

Let V be a class with a single attribute named K and its getter and setters.

What's supposed to happen if I do:

```
V v = new V();
v.setK("a");
HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
map.put(v.getk(),v);
v.setK("b");
```

As far as I know, this should cause some kind of problem because a map key is supposed to be invariable. What would happen here?

Edit: Consider the key not to be a String but a mutable object as stated in the coment below.

Comment: Scenario with a problem is when you object K[ey] is a complex object itself. For example, contains attribute A and K calculates own hashCode based on A value. In that case, if A changed after you use K as key in map - it's violation of Map contract. Quote from JavaDoc: _great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map_.

Comment: Of course, my bad. I always meant this case, using a String as Key was just a bad example. I'm editing the question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of this question is misleading -- you are not changing the map key, as in *mutating the object used as map key*. When you say `map.put(x, y)`, you are creating a *map entry* that aggregates two independent values: a *key* and a *value*. Where the key originates from is not seen by the map, it's just two objects. So, you have created a map entry `("a", v)` and after that you just changed the state of v -- there is no way this could have influenced the map entry's key "a". If, on the other hand, you had an object K of your own making, like

```
public class K { 
  private String s;
  public K(String s) { this.s = s; }
  public void setS(String s) { this.s = s; }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { return ((K)o).s.equals(this.s); }
  public int hashCode() { return s.hashCode(); }
```

}

and now you do

```
final K k = new K("a");
map.put(k, v);
k.setS("b");
map.get(k);
```

then you would face the problem -- you **mutated the object used as the map key**.

Answer (score 6):

Quote from "Map" interface JavaDoc:

> *Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map.*

You simply shouldn't mutate keys (in the way which changes their "hashCode"/"equals"). You will definitely have very long and awful debugging if you try.
It's like you swap books in the library. Index became unreliable. You search for "Bradbury", but find "Simak".

Comment: You should add that your observation only applies if the class overrides `equals()` *and* attribute `k` is used by it. (ie if the value of `k` affects `equals()`)

Comment: @Bohemian Added phrase in round braces to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

If you were trying to look up the map using `v.getk()` it wouldn't find an entry, because you've changed the value return by the getter on v.

Or in other words, the map isn't magically kept in sync with what happens to your v object - it uses (and keeps using) the value given to it in the `put()`.

Comment: *" ... the map isn't magically kept in sync ... "* - and one reason is that the map has no way of knowing that the key has changed,

Answer (score 2):

```
V v = new V();
v.setK("a");
HashMap<K,V> map = new HashMap<K,V>();
map.put(v.getk(),v);

//Nothing will change in the hashmap with this step
v.setK("b");
```

but the problem will be while fetching the object V from map. If you call map.get(v.getk()), you will get null because the value in the map is mapped with object "a". However, since this String "a" is inter you can always fetch this object from map by `map.get("a");` or

```
V v = new V();
v.setK("a");
map.get(v.getK());
```

PS: I have not tried to run this

Answer (score 1):

By calling v.setK(), you aren't changing the key in the HashMap. So you will simply have wrong information in your V object.

Comment: So, put() actually calls clone() on the key and stores it, yes?

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc: No, not at all... Since you are using a HashMap, it simply uses the HashCode as identifier.

Comment: Mmmm... if it only stores the hashCode of the Key, how comes I can retrieve the original keys?

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc: Because it stores the original keys in the Entry[] array inside the HashMap class.

Comment: So, it's calling clone to store it on Entry[] and then hashing it?

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc - He did not say "it only stores the hashCode of the Key".

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc: No, it doesn't use clone. It simply stores the same instance of the Key object in the Entry array.

Comment: I'm actually a bit confused. If I'm understanding this, after changing the key from the outside, the original key stored in Entry[] will change because it's the same instance, however, the value will not change of position because it was placed by using the hash of the original key, leaving the map in a state where one of the keys stored in Entry[] references to an invalid position inside the map?

Comment: @Hallucynogenyc: No, again you are wrong :D. By assigning a value to a variable, that single variable will change. This doesn't mean that every instance of a class in your whole program will be replaced by the new object. Eg: `String s = "string"; String s2 = s; String s3 = "three"; s = s3;` Right now, s2 will be still "string".