# Complex data structures: simplicity vs transparency

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

For example, let's assume that the following data structures all implement the mapping of Lemmas->PartsOfSpeech->ListOfWords (topic choice is arbitrary and has nothing to do with question):

```
Map<ArrayList<Lemma>, Map<PartOfSpeech, ArrayList<Word>>> mainMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<ArrayList<Lemma>, PartOfSpeechWordMap> mainMap = new HashMap<>();

LemmaMap mainMap = new LemmaMap();
```

Where `PartOfSpeechWordMap` contains and manipulates `Map<PartOfSpeech, ArrayList<Word>>`, and `LemmaMap` contains and manipulates one of the above structures.

The list goes from most transparent and complicated, to least transparent and simplest; however, I'm not sure which is best from an object oriented perspective. As you go down the list, it gets more and more difficult to figure out what's going on, despite being more concise and having simpler syntax.

I understand that this question may be a little subjective, but I'd like to know if there are standard industry practices when dealing with something like this.

EDIT:
I wasn't thinking and didn't consider the issue with mutable keys.  Let's assume that I'm using `ImmutableList` per Guava.  Nonetheless, the point of my question was which structure makes most sense from an OOP perspective with regards to the varying levels of transparency.

Comment: Whatever you do, [**do not use mutable keys in a `Map`.**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10153537/139010)

Comment: What do you mean by that?  The `ArrayList` shouldn't change or the elements of the `ArrayList`, themselves shouldn't change.

Comment: Two other options using Guava: `Table<ArrayList<Lemma>, PartOfSpeech, ArrayList<Word>>` or `Map<ArrayList<Lemma>, Multimap<PartOfSpeech, Word>>`

Comment: The point is that a `List` is mutable and can therefore change, since it's hashcode would then change, the value to which it is mapped would be lost FOREVER. If it can't change, you could use an `ImmutableList` per `Guava`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a

```
class LemmaMap implements Map<List<Lemma>, Map<PartOfSpeech, List<Word>>>
```

where `LemmaMap` wraps a `HashMap`, but also provides some additional methods e.g.

```
public List<Word> getAllWords(List<Lemma> key) {
    List<Word> returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<Word> list : map.get(key).values()) {
        returnValue.addAll(list);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

This provides transparency while also hiding the map from callers who e.g. only want the list of all words associated with a key without caring how to get it from the underlying map

Comment: Is there a way to get around the mutable key issue with `List<Lemma`?  Or would you have to use [ImmutableList](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)?

Comment: @Steve P. Use `ImmutableList` from Guava or `UnmodifiableList` from Apache Commons

Comment: @Steve P. You can also write your own list wrapper that automatically removes the list from the map prior to modification, and puts the list back in the map after modification - just be warned that this can be rather complicated if you have multiple threads accessing the maps / lists

Answer (score 1):

I will say that this is not the appropriate site for this question but I believe most people would suggest using the simplest to use API. This gives the advantage to reducing the likelihood that it will be used improperly (such as adding elements to the key array). It also allows you to change the underlying implementation detail should the need arise.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure if SO was the right site, but sometimes people answer questions like this one.  As you did, so thank you.